# Make Remote Repository as it was yesterday

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

On GitLab, My remote repository was good till yesterday.
Today I just wanted to try Merge Request feature of GitLab.

Due to lack of knowledge, I messed up with my remote repo.
My local repo is still good.
And I have done tons of important changes to my local repo.

Without having my remote repo as it was yesterday, I am not able to push my local work to remote.

Please let me know if we can revert our remote repo to the way it was before one day.
Or can I have my local repo pushed to remote without losing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only person who is working with that remote repository you can force a push to the repository by `git push --force`. This will overwrite the remote repository with your local version. This may break things for other developers who have cloned that repository. So if yours is not the single clone you should fix the problem and do a clean `push` without forcing. You wrote nothing about the real problem you have when pushing so currently the only advice can be to do a forced push.

By default GitLab forbids forced pushes. You first have to remove that protection. Click the cogwheel icon in your project and select `Protected branches`. Then click the `Unprotect` button for the master branch. The forced push will work then.

Comment: When I click on Push button on source Tree, that gives me an error
" ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)"

Will try doing unprotected option